# Conceptually, how would I approach creating this image in react (text alignment)

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm currently building a recipe and meal planning app for a personal project and I'm struggling on converting this image into react. Sectioning and spacing specifically. **How should I approach the sectioning?**
I currently have it is that the meals, days of the week, and "breakfast lunch dinner" will have their own `div`s. Is this the best way of going about it or is there a more effective way?

What i want: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eb5zL.jpg

What I have: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nSXZR.jpg

I created some test cards and gave them this css

```
.mealplancard{ 
    display:flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    justify-content:space-evenly;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    margin: 20px;
    border: 1px solid black; /*so I can see  where the div starts and ends*/
    border-radius: 25px;
    width: 66%;
    float: right;
  }
```

Width 66% allows me to have cards per row which is what I need for my meals.
**My second question is how do I align the Days of the week column to line up evenly with each row of food?** Since I'm struggling with divs I'm not sure how to go about this. All relavant code is attached below. I am also getting my recipe info from an API.

```
const MealPlanCard = ({title, calories, image, ingredients}) => {

    const round = Math.round(calories);
        
    return(

        <div className>
            
            <div className= "row">
                <div className = "card">
                        <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/> 
                        <h1 >{title}</h1>
                    </div>
                
                <div className = "column">
                    <div className = "card">
                        <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/> 
                        <h1 >{title}</h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div className = "card">
                        <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/> 
                        <h1 >{title}</h1>
                    </div>
                    <div className = "card">
                        <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/> 
                        <h1 >{title}</h1>
                    </div>    

                    <div className = "card">
                        <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/> 
                        <h1 >{title}</h1>
                    </div>   

                    <div className = "card">
                        <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/> 
                        <h1 >{title}</h1>
                    </div>   

                    <div className = "card">
                        <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/> 
                        <h1 >{title}</h1>
                    </div>   

                    <div className = "card">
                        <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/> 
                        <h1 >{title}</h1>
                    </div>   

                    <div className = "card">
                        <img className = {style.image} src={image} alt=""/> 
                        <h1 >{title}</h1>
                    </div>   


            </div>
        </div>
        )

    }




    return(
            <div className = "App">
                <NavigationBar></NavigationBar>


                <div className = {style.mealplantext}>
                    <h1>monday</h1>
                    <h1>tuesday</h1>
                    <h1>wednesday</h1>
                </div>




                <div className = {style.mealplancard}>
                    {recipes.slice(0, 1).map(recipe =>(
                        <MealPlanCard 
                        key={recipe.recipe.label}
                        title ={recipe.recipe.label} 
                        calories={recipe.recipe.calories}
                        image={recipe.recipe.image}
                        ingredients={recipe.recipe.ingredients}
                        />
                    ))}
             </div>
```

Edit: Bolded  the actual questions for clarity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to make the **Monday**, **Tuesday**, **etc** at the same line with the menu(s), you should put them in the same `row`.

Basically You should put them in this kind of structure:

```
row
|
+-- col
|   |
|   +-- h1 (the day)
|
+--col
   |
   +--row
       |
       +--col
       |  |
       |  +-- card
       |
       +--col
          |
          +-- card
```

Here is an example built with boostrap and simple HTML/CSS/JS for it:

```css
.row {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center; 
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col day"><b>Monday</b></div>
  <div class="col">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="card">
          <img class="card-img-top" src="https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/08/coffee_terrine-0c48191.jpg?quality=90&resize=500%2C454" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Pudding</h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```